# Show UIAlertController every time view controller launches

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Currently, the UIAlertController appears when the user taps on the HeaderButton. I am trying to make the UIAlertController automatically appear every time the view controller initially launches. Any suggestions?

```
// MARK: - RestaurantListTableViewHeaderDelegate
extension RestaurantListViewController: RestaurantListTableViewHeaderDelegate {
  func didTapHeaderButton(_ headerView: RestaurantListTableViewHeader) {
    let locationPicker = UIAlertController(title: "Select location", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    for location in RestaurantListViewController.locations {
      locationPicker.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: location, style: .default) { [weak self] action in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
        self.currentLocation = action.title
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      })
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    locationPicker.addAction(cancelAction)
    present(locationPicker, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept the extension for when the Header Button gets tapped and I added the following to viewDidLoad:

```
// Code for showing alert
let locationPicker = UIAlertController(title: "Select location", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
for location in RestaurantListViewController.locations {
  locationPicker.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: location, style: .default) { [weak self] action in
    guard let `self` = self else { return }
    self.currentLocation = action.title
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  })
}
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
locationPicker.addAction(cancelAction)
present(locationPicker, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an elegant solution but it will work:

```
var alertAlreadyShown = false

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  if !alertAlreadyShown {
      alertAlreadyShown = true
      /* Code for showing alert */
  }
}
```

Comment: This was helpful, but unfortunately this will make the UIAlertController appear when the user goes back to that view controller from a details view controller. I only want it to show at every initial launch.